# I cant migrate Category model. No such column: blog_catergory_id. How can I fix this?

Tags: django, django-models, datatable, database-migration

I already checked some of other posts with similar problems. I`v done all of that...
I tried to delete all migrations then to migrate again. I went for syncdb option also.

Still i get this error : http://prntscr.com/nxuq1d
no such table.

Im using django 2.5.1 version

EDIT: After rewriting spelling mistake with category almost same error occured.
This time it says : no such column: blog_category_id - > http://prntscr.com/nxvv4r

here is the code

models.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        help_text="A short label, generally used in URLs.", default='', max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

0001_initial.py ..my only migrations. i deleted all then i migrated again

```
import ckeditor_uploader.fields
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(max_length=150)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'catergory',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'catergories',
                'ordering': ('name',),
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(default='', help_text='A short label, generally used in URLs.', max_length=100)),
                ('image', models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')),
                ('content', ckeditor_uploader.fields.RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('date_posted', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('category', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='blog.Category')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['-date_posted'],
            },
        ),
    ]
```

template file - blog_view

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<main class="mt-5 pt-5">
        <div class="container">


          <section class="card wow fadeIn" style="background-image: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/gradient1.jpg);">

            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="card-body text-white text-center py-5 px-5 my-5">

              <h1 class="mb-4">
                <strong>Učite kuvanje sa mnom</strong>
              </h1>
              <h2 class="big-headline">
                <strong>BLOG</strong>
              </h2>
              <p class="mb-4">
                <strong>Najbolji i besplatni saveti kako da od običnog kuvara postanete sef kuhinje</strong>
              </p>
              <a target="_blank" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-lg">Kontaktirajte me 
                <i class="fas fa-utensils ml-2"></i>
              </a>

            </div>

          </section>





<!-- posts -->



              <section>

                <h2 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center pt-5" style="color: #333;">Naši Postovi</h2>
                <hr class="mb-5 line-split">
                <p class="text-center dark-grey-text w-responsive mx-auto p-2">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
                  voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


                {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="row pt-5">

                  <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
                    <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-1-half mb-lg-0 mb-4">
                      <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="Sample image">
                      <a>
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                      </a>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-7 col-xl-8">
                    <h3 class="font-weight-bold mb-3"><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></h3>
                    <p class="dark-grey-text">{{ post.content|truncatechars:255}}</p>
                    <p>by <a class="font-weight-bold">{{ post.author }}</a>, {{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</p>
                    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Read more</a>
                  </div>

                </div>
              <hr class="my-5">
              {% endfor %}
              </section>
              <!-- Section: Blog v.3 -->

        </div>
</main>

<div class="container text-center">
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if posts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; 1 - </a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">predhodna</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Stranica {{ posts.title }} broj {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if posts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import PostDetailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index_view, name='index-page'),
    path('blog/', views.blog_view, name='blog-page'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.contrib import messages
from . models import Post
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView


def index_view(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index_view.html')


def blog_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_view.html', {'posts': posts})


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
```

BASE.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette|EB+Garamond|Prompt" rel="stylesheet">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.16/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/animate.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">>
  {% if title %}
  <title>Pocetna- {{ title }}</title>
  {% else %}
  <title>Pocetna</title>
  {% endif %}

</head>

<body>
  <header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-steel fixed-top">
      <div class="w-75 container-fluid">
        <a class="logo nav-link" href="{% url 'index-page' %}">Tri Musketara</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
          <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          </div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link nav-page" style="color:#f3f3f3;" href="{% url 'index-page' %}">Početna</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link nav-page" style="color:#f3f3f3;" href="{% url 'about-page' %}">O Nama</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color:#f3f3f3;" href="{% url 'blog-page' %}">Blog</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="color:#f3f3f3;" href="#" id="#navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Usluge
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Postavka kuhinje</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kuvanje na Vašoj adresi</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'recipes-page' %}">Recepti</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ketering</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color:#f3f3f3;" href="{% url 'contact-page' %}">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container-fluid"></div>
  {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </div>

  <footer class="container-fluid pt-4 footer pt-5">
    <div class="container text-center text-md-left">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
          <div class="logo pt-5">aa</div>
          <h5 class="text-uppercase pt-5">Footer Content</h5>
          <p>Here you can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
        </div>
        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
          <h5 class="text-uppercase pt-5">Links</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled pt-5">
            <li>
              <a href="#!"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
          <h5 class="text-uppercase pt-5">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled pt-5">
            <li>
              <a href="{% url 'contact-page' %}">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Recepti</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">O nama</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




  </footer>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    baguetteBox.run('.compact-gallery', { animation: 'slideIn' });
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.16/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>

  <script>  new WOW().init();  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 4
          }
        }, {
          breakpoint: 520,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2
          }
        }]
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: drop your DB and try again.

Comment: omg...i made this question and i didnt even bother to check my spelling.. Thanks guys

Comment: if you deleted you migrations and then did makemigrations again, without updating the django_migrations table, then the django thinks you've applied your migrations and won't migrate

Comment: at first i deleted migrations forlder but then i did python manage.py memakigration <app name>. So its ok. I made mistake in spelling and i didnt even saw that lol

Comment: show your settings.py file

Comment: it still not working. I deleted that R in Meta: verbose and still i have same issue

Comment: now its blog_category_id  -> http://prntscr.com/nxva06

Comment: Edit your question and add the template code as well.

Comment: Please also share your base.html file

Comment: Done. I added base.html file

Comment: Are you using blog_post.category_id somewhere in your views.py file or in template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194484/discussion-between-chirag-soni-and-veljko-kukic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do changes at these lines:

Replace

```
 verbose_name = 'catergory'
    verbose_name_plural = 'catergories'
```

to

```
verbose_name = 'category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
```

Comment: did that...then i delted 0001_initial.py migration and i migrated again and same issue :(

Comment: did you replaced two lines whatever I suggested?

Comment: You are using `catergory` instead of  `category`. check spelling.

Comment: now i have this error http://prntscr.com/nxva06

Comment: yes i did that Sir, i wrote cetegory instead of catergory in both places...but now i get this error with ID

Comment: So basically problem with migrations i.e. earlier error got relolved right?

Comment: now definitly is something about migrations or ID of that category. Check my printscreens in answers below

Comment: to resolve the new issue delete old migrations and again migrate from scratch as it is pointing to the old migrations that is why you are getting the new kind of error.

Comment: and please make a habit of appreciating the people who answer you and try to help you resolve your problem. Dont' mind please it is just a advice to get good answer.

Comment: thanks for your answers chiiag soni... I deleted whole folder of migrations...then i did python manage.py makemigrations <app name>. still not working i get same error -> no such table: blog_category_id

Comment: IN your template I guess you are using `category_id` you should use `category__id` instead.